# Transitions between pages not worked by using CSS in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxt.js

I couldn't find any transition effects when page changed.

app.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>
<style>
.page-enter-active,
.page-leave-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.page-enter-from,
.page-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

/pages/index.vue:

```
<template>
    <div>
      <h1>Home page</h1>
      <NuxtLink to="/about">About page</NuxtLink>
    </div>
</template>
```

/pages/about.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>About page</h1>
    <NuxtLink to="/">Home page</NuxtLink>
  </div>
</template>
```

Expecting the page shows gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Add a configuration in `nuxt.config.ts`, it worked.

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  app: {
    pageTransition: { name: 'page', mode: 'out-in' }
  },
})
```